# Django HTML template to pdf consisting JS (Vue.js) charts and graphs

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF from Html page. The Html includes various data returned from django view and also from Vue.js

I tried using 'Weasyprint' but it only generated data that returned from Django but not the charts and graphs that were generated from Vue. What will be an easy way to generate all the data as well as the graphs in PDF from the Html page.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a PDF with those charts, you will need to render the web-page first (in a browser) in order to run the client-side code and use that "result" to generate the final PDF.

It will depend on where you want to generate that PDF (on the server or on the client). In case it is on the server, one possible solution is to use `phantomJS` (or other similar projects) to render and save the result in a file with [`render()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html).